# не срабатывает $("#submit-button").on('click',function () {}

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Есть View:

```html
@model DTOLibrary.PositionDto

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<div class="container" style="width:40%"; margin-top:2%>

    <form id="form">

        @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Name, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Name" })

        @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Salary, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Salary" })

        <input type="submit"  value="Submit" class="btn-block btn-primary" id="submit-button"/>

    </form>

</div>


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        console.log('your message');
        $("#submit-button").on('click',function () {
            $("#loaderDiv").show();
         
            var Data = $("#form").serialize();
            console.log(Data);
            $.ajax({
                
            type: "POST",
             url: "/Position/Edit",
            data: Data,
                succsess: function (response) {
                    $("#loaderDiv").hide();
                alert("you are done ");
            }
            })
        })
    })

</script>
```

в стрипте должен выполняться Post запрос к контроллеру, но при дебаге выяснил что после обращении к функции

```js
$("#submit-button").on('click',function () {
```

оно идет в конец пропуская её выполнение, где я допустил ошибку?

Answer (score 2):

При нажатии на кнопку "#submit-button" срабатывании события submit и происходит перерисовка страницы и соответственно js не успевает выполнится.

Нужно отметить submit для этого требуется использовать "e.preventDefault();"

```
    $("#submit-button").on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
       // you code
    }
```

Так же отмечу, что событие submit лучше отслеживать через его вызов, а не через нажатие на кнопки

```
    $("#form").on('submit',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
       // you code
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет=)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#submit-button").on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#loaderDiv").show();
        ...
```

или

```
  <input type="button" ...
```

---

> идет в конец пропуская её выполнение

Эта строчка не выполняет анонимную функцию, а прикрепляет ее к кнопке в качества обработчика события `click`.

Comment: Спасибо, понял исправлю=)